# iTunes starts playing when disconnecting Bose Soundlink Mini

Tags: itunes, macbook-pro, bluetooth

i have a Bose Soundlink Mini connected to a Macbook Air. When the Soundlink turns off after a time (because of energy saver mode), iTunes automatically starts playing music. I didn't find any option to disable that, nor any information about others with the same problem. Do you have any idea, why this happens and how i can solve it?

Comment: Could you check what you have in the /Library/iTunes/iTunes Plug-ins/

Comment: Dunno about OP but I have Quartz Composer Visualizer.bundle. This is happening on the disconnect w/ Bose Soundlink though so I dunno how much iTunes plugins are related to the problem.

Comment: Same for me here, Quartz Composer Visualizer.bundle only.

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: I have the same problem when I disconnect the EarBud from MB Air Mid 2012. It happens pretty much with every other device too. I’ve learnt to live with it, but a solution would be nice. I think it’s because iTunes used to have feature where it would stop playing music when a device was disconnected from the port, but some how it got inverted; to start playing

Answer (score 1):

This (http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-stop-itunes-from-opening-with-bluetooth-speakers.1666895/) worked for me --

In Finder go to Applications and show package contents on iTunes.app. Inside the MacOS folder there is a unix script called iTunes, I renamed it iTunesclosed. Also renamed ituneshelper.app to ituneshelpdisabled.app

Remove the iTunesHelper.app from starting on login via System Preferences -> Users and Groups

Also kill the iTunesHelper process via Activity Monitor.

Edit: Note that you may have to do this every time iTunes is updated.